# Spring and manually created DAOs how to refactor to enable hasPermisions on such DAOs objects

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have got Dao implentation like this

```
public class EntityDao<T> {

    private Class clazz;
    private SessionFactory sessFactory;

    public EntityDao(Class clazz, SessionFactory sessFactory) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.sessFactory = sessFactory;

    }
.... dao methods 
}
```

and factory for retriving and storing particular dao

```
EntityBeanDaoFactory {

private HashMap<EntityDaoType, EntityDao> daoMap = new HashMap<EntityDaoType, EntityDao>();
// return dao from daoMap if exists a if not create it and put it in the map then return dao
public EntityDao createDao(EntityDaoType entityType)  {
 switch (entityType) {
        case mySpecialDaoTYPE:
            if (!daoMap.containsKey(entityType)) {
                    EntityDao<Type> mySpecialDao = new EntityDao(Type.class, sessFactory);
                    daoMap.put(entityType, mySpecialDao);
                }
                 return daoMap.get(entityType);
}

}
```

now I want to annotate dao methods with   @PreAuthorize("hasPermission()")  but spring doesn't know about daos created this way and I am not able to refactor whole project at once so I have created dao ,on wich I need to use the annotation, inside aplicationContectxt.xml

```
<bean id="mySpecialDao" class="..EntityDao" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>myClass</value> 
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

inside the factory I have changet behavior for creating this particular dao like this

```
     if (!daoMap.containsKey(entityType)) {
         EntityDao<Class> dao = (EntityDao<Class>) AppContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("mySpecialDao");
                daoMap.put(entityType, dao);
            }
```

is there some better way how to make spring aware of my DAOs ? I mean is there way how to make Spring  aware of manualy created instancess ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using Spring AOP support using AspectJ. Read more here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

After enabling this, Spring would be aware of any instances created of classes annotated with the Configurable annotation. Spring would then be able to recognize the PreAuthorize annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a factory to create DAOs?  That's what the Spring application context is.

You look like you want to restrict the ability to call DAO methods using role based security.  I think that's fine, and possible to do, but you need not restrict creation of the DAO.  Create it using Spring and then restrict access.  Your way is overkill and unnecessary.

Comment: the factory is allredy there and it is hardcoded on so many places so its dificult to get it rid of it (It wasn't me :-) ). I dont need to restrict call to dao or its methods but to implement some sort of ACL based on curent user a target entity ID so I have own permisionEvaluator (hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission))